# Display data by id with the sequence id of the loop

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to show data by id, but with random id sequence from the loop

This is my button:

```html
<button id="nextButton" data-id="{{$data_number->id}}" data-no="{{ $key_number }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-md" style="margin-left:20px !important;"> 
  Selanjutnya
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

This is my random loop id:

```
29 14 12 43 16 33 44 19 5 3 34 30 25 37 31 18 36 11 41 17 38 1 48 28 50 40 15 22 47 45 42 6 8 10 4 26 23 2 9 35 32 13 21 39 49 20 24 46 7 27
```

The random number id, result form:

```
@foreach($soals as $data_number)
  {{$data_number->id}}
@endforeach
```

This is my jQuery:

```js
$('#nextButton').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('#wrap-soal').html('<center><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size: 30 pt; color: #12b9cc; margin: 15px;" aria-hidden= "true"></i></center>');
    $('#no_soal_detail').html($this.attr('data-no'));
    var id_soal = $this.attr('data-id'); $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{{ url('siswa/ujian/get-soal') }}/" + id_soal,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#wrap-soal').html(data);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

I want when I press the button with id `nextButton` it will show data by order of random loop id

Comment: Please make it clear what the question, unable to understand the question.

Comment: how do I display the data based on the order of the number?

Comment: try sort($soals); before the loop will help you

Comment: the rule is that the data must be displayed randomly

Comment: I am sorry I am still unable to understand can you please update your question with proper details which id and what should be random, can you please provide some proper examples of what actually is required?

Comment: for the example i have random number like :
29 14 12 43 16 33 44 19 5 3 34 30

so I want to display the data with the data id based on the sequence of those numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247143/discussion-between-prateik-darji-and-dwi-prihta).